# Matplotlib not plotting sorted dataset in correct order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a similar dataset to the following

```
Group       Values
-------     -------
Group A       5
Group B       2
Group C       10
```

I sorted the dataset by doing:

```
dataset2 = data.sort_values(by= 'Values', ascending=False)
```

When I display `dataset2` it correctly displays the dataset in the correct descending order. However, when I plot `dataset2` with `matplotlib` it plots it using the original data order; not the sorted one.

```
left = dataset2.index.values

height = dataset2['Values']  # heights of bars
tick_label = dataset2['Group']  # labels for bars

# plotting a bar chart
plt.bar(left, height, tick_label = tick_label, width = 0.8)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens when you output `dataset2['Values']`?

Comment: The whole point of an index is that it does not change if you sort the dataframe. So the output stays the same, i.e. "GroupA" would still have index 0, even though it is at the second row of the sorted dataframe. You may create a new index to plot against, instead of using the old one.

Comment: basic trouble shooting: `print(left)`. what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I as able to solve this issue doing two things:

1) making a copy of the sorted dataset.

```
data_sorted = dataset2.copy()
```

2) Changing the left to:

```
left = np.arange(len(data_sorted))
```

for some reason when I was using the index to set up the x axis it was using the original index from the original dataset. I thought that when you sorted the values the index was reset.